# Can Hadoop 3.2 HDFS client be used to work with Hadoop 2.x HDFS nodes?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, hadoop2

I am trying to build a Java program using Hadoop 3.2 client. Will it be able to work with Hadoop 2.x clusters? Or, is it not supported? Thank you for sharing your experience.

Answer (score 2):

With Hadoop and most Apache-licensed projects compatibility is only guaranteed between minor version numbers.  So you should not expect a 3.2 client to work with a 2.x Hadoop cluster.

Cloudera's blog [Upgrading your clusters and workloads from Apache Hadoop 2 to Apache Hadoop 3](https://blog.cloudera.com/upgrading-clusters-workloads-hadoop-2-hadoop-3/) written by Suma Shivaprasad also mentions the following:

> ### Compatibility with Hadoop 2
>
> #### Wire compatibility
>
> - Hadoop 3 preserves wire compatibility with Hadoop 2 clients
> - Distcp/WebHDFS compatibility is preserved
>
> #### API compatibility
>
> Hadoop 3 doesn’t preserve full API level compatibility due to the following changes
>
> - Classpath – Dependency version bumps like guava
> - Removal of deprecated APIs and tools
> - Shell script rewrites
> - Incompatible bug fixes

But also states:

> ### Migrating Workloads
>
> #### MapReduce applications
>
> MapReduce is fully binary compatible and workloads should run as is without any changes required.